# はね。。。at the end of a sentence

Tags: ellipsis

I'm facing this sentence

> お父さんがまだ生きてる頃はね...

I think I'm able to guess the meaning which may sounds as "When my father was still alive...." but the "ending" はね is gonna puzzling me. I suppose there's some ellipsis (copula omitted) or it's just an emphatic expression (maybe the same)?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the sentence before that one?

Comment: A guy is asking よく来たの？ (did you came here often?) and subject replied うん、お父さんがまだ生きてる頃はね... maybe the subject is thinking when the father was still alive so there's an 思う omitted? I don't know.

Comment: I would assume, the ね is used in place of a repetition -> お父さんがまだ生きてる頃は よく来たんだ;

Answer (score 3):

The sentence in question is a "partial" sentence in which the main verb is omitted. Similar things happen very often in English, too:

> よく来たの？
> Did [you] come (here) often?
>
> うん、お父さんがまだ生きてる頃はね...
> Yeah, when Dad was still alive ([I] used to come here)...
>
> <sub>(The subject may be "she" or someone else instead of "you/I".)</sub>

The "full" version of the sentence is お父さんがまだ生きてる頃はよく来た, but よく来た is left out since it's redundant. This は is a topic marker, and it's almost mandatory here because it has a contrastive nuance (i.e., now this person no longer visits the place). ね is just a sentence-end/filler particle.

BTW, please try to provide the full context when asking a question like this. No one can tell the omitted verb without the context.

Comment: This may not be the right place to ask but in the disappointing sounding sentence "グラビアなんか読んでるなんてね～", where the ね～ is read like ↗︎, is this also just filler particle that doesn't have much meaning? https://www.pixiv.net/novel/show.php?id=17248725

Comment: @firuvi No, ね as an interjectory/filler particle and ね as a sentence-end particle are different. You can easily find articles about the latter.