# Leaving out endings to sentences

Tags: syntax, spoken-language

A lot of times, endings to sentences are omitted for some reason. For example, "konna ni ooki na tatemono no naka ni ita to wa" may be completed by something like "omowanakatta". I can't fully remember other ones but there are times sentences end in "wo" that would be completed by ending something like "inorimasu" or "[...]te kudasai". I know the endings should be obvious in most cases but is this kind of a thing more formal speech or casual speech, and is it more common in speech than in written Japanese? Is there a linguistic term for this?

Comment: Possible duplciate/related: ["unfinished" sentences ending in particles like を, に and が](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11624/unfinished-sentences-ending-in-particles-like-%e3%82%92-%e3%81%ab-and-%e3%81%8c); [はね。。。at the end of a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74395/11792).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [まだいたとはね meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30285/%e3%81%be%e3%81%a0%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af%e3%81%ad-meaning)